# Почему в разных браузерах по разному отображается padding ?

Tags: css

Пробовал даже сделать обычную рамку, внутри разместить текст. В хроме настраиваю padding, чтобы отступ получился 10px с четырех сторон - отображается нормально. Открываю Mozilla Firefox - измеряю (FastStone), отступ 9px... (

C чем это может быть связано ?

Comment: Проблемную верстку и стили в студию

padding везде отображается одинаково, неодинаково может отрисоваться текст, к примеру, от которого ты, видимо, отталкиваешься, замеряя этот отступ глазом.

Comment: были мысли, что может быть проблема в тексте, но решил все таки уточнить.

Bars, не набросаешь простой пример с ровными отступами с четырех сторон ?

Comment: Шутишь? Вот: http://jsfiddle.net/LXJcY/

Comment: не вооруженным глазом ведь видно, что отступ с верху больше чем с низу. Если ваш текст выделить (http://s019.radikal.ru/i640/1301/fe/bb9cbefa42fc.gif) - отступ будет 10px со всех сторон. А если не выделять - отступ с верху получается 12px, с лева 12px, с низу 11px. Если не верите - измерьте с помощью FastStone. Там четко измеряется px...

P.S.Я свой вопрос уже решил (http://i023.radikal.ru/1301/9c/877384305907.gif) отображается идеально ровно во всех браузерах.

Comment: http://s13.radikal.ru/i186/1301/69/dfa803960877.gif - The page cannot be found (страница не найдена)

Comment: @Яковлев Андрей, дело в том, что по сути @Родион Поляков сам нашел решение своей проблемы, а мой ответ выбрал как правильный, вероятно в благодарность за моральную поддержку. 

Так что, Вы уж сильно не ругайтесь...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот [здесь почитайте](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/css-tricks/reset-margin-padding.html)

Необходимо использовать reset.css или

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

Но первый вариант предпочтительнее.

Comment: * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

Прописывал. А вот про reset.css первый раз слышу. Нужно будет больше в это углубится. )))

Comment: @Родион Поляков, ну что, как успехи с reset.css? Помогло?

Comment: Не помогло (((

Comment: Ну тогда выкладываете Ваш код на jsfiddle.net, - посмотрим вечерком.

Comment: @Родион Поляков, или киньте мне на мыло(в профиле указано), с комментарием, что, где и как...

Comment: Наверное таких доброжелательных людей можно встретить только на hashcode. )))

Полазил по сайтам сегодня, посмотрел как у других сделано.

Убрал у себя:

font-size: 16px; 

И прописал вот так:

font: 16px/22px "Trebuchet MS", Tahoma, Arial;

Проблема решилась )))

Спасибо тебе за помощь...

Comment: @Родион Поляков, без проблем! Обращайся если что...

Удачи!

Comment: Хотя вообще странно, что шрифт и line-height влияли на padding'и...
Думаю, что основная причина все-таки не в этом...

Comment: Может и в чем то другом была проблема, а на свежую голову сделал все правильно. )))

Конечный результат: (http://s13.radikal.ru/i186/1301/69/dfa803960877.gif)

Comment: блин, ответ отмечен как правильный, а решение в комментариях. вы ведь так смуту наводите на пользователей...